# .NET 6 how to add webservice reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How can I add reference to SOAP web service (.asmx) in .NET 6.

In .NET Framework there is Web references in VS with autogenerated proxy classes. How to can I migrate .NET Framework project with web references to .NET 6 ?

Comment: Just Googled ".net 6 connect to web service" and the first link was [Use the WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)

Comment: I tried but I’m getting wierd error in VS

Comment: What is the "weird error"? It really helps to know what you've tried and what problems you ran in to.

Comment: The Connected Services component 'Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider' failed: The project reference specification 'System.Web.Services' does not have a file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your actual error,

> The Connected Services component 'Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference
> Provider' failed: The project reference specification
> 'System.Web.Services' does not have a file path.

maybe you are hitting the same issue as stated here: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/4713 ?

Their fix seems to be:

> Remove this,
>
> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>     <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel">
>       <Private>false</Private>
>     </Reference>    
> </ItemGroup>
> ```

but the other comment might also be important:

> Update: fix of the issue would be available in the upcoming Visual
> Studio 2022 release.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this check in the wizard to add Service Reference:
[image]

Comment: why????????????