# .NET 6 how to add webservice reference to a VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net

I am aware of this thread [.NET 6 how to add webservice reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365225/net-6-how-to-add-webservice-reference) but I am creating a VB.NET desktop app and when I go to *Connected Services*, I don't have the option of selecting *Service References* as in C#. Only *Service Dependencies*. Is there a workaround?